# UIAlertView in viewWillDisappear

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

when the user presses the Back-Button on my UINavigationController View, I want to show a UIAlertView with 2 options. One option (OK) allows the user to go back (to the previous screen), the other one (Cancel) will stay at the current controller.

I implemented the following code (which I found here on so) in my viewWillDisappear:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
        // back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer
        // in the navigation stack.


        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"All Data will be lost" 
                                                        message:@"You must be connected to the internet to use this app." 
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        alert.tag = 1;
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

}
```

The problem is, that after I pressed Back, the view jumps immediately to the previos screen und dispay on this screen the UIAlertView.

In the UIAlertView callback method I used the following coding, but nothing happens (I think this is, cause I've been at this point already on the previous view):

```
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 1)
                 NSLog(@"back");
//Go Back ...
}
```

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 6):

By the time `viewWillDisappear` is being called it's too late. The navigation controller has already dismissed the view controller.

Instead, you need to intercept the back button touch event. You can do this in a number of ways - you could have a custom back button, which displays your `UIAlertView`. Or you could use the `UINavigationBarDelegate`, which has a `navigationBar:shouldPopItem:` method.

Comment: work partly. But when I want to navigate from the previous one back to the current one I get an error, that manual handling the controllers is not allowed. If you have no UINavigationController which handles the "back"-navigation. this solution works like a charme.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code for UIAlertView in the back button method, and when you click the back button it simply shows the alert, when you click the button it simply calls the `clickedbuttonindex:`  method and in this method you just call the view which you want.

```
-(IBAction)back-button{
   //alert
}



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
   //call the view
}
```